# How to read UTF file char by char in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf

I have UTF-8 file and I want to replace some characters that are 2 bytes with some HTML tags.

I wanted to make Python script for that. Just read file, char by char, and put some if and so on.

Problem that I have is following, if I read char by char, that I am reading one byte, but some characaters are 1 byte and some are 2 bytes long.

How to solve it ?

I basically need feature that will read char by char, but it will know is this char size of 1 or 2 byte.

Comment: It will be helpful to post the code you have written so far, also point out what python version you're using.

Comment: By "char" you mean a code point? They go up to 6 bytes in UTF-8

Comment: Please at least post the examples of your files content and how you want to read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open the file while specifying the correct encoding. In Python 3, that's done using

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as myfile:
    contents = myfile.read()
    for char in contents:
        # do something with character
```

In Python 2, you can use the [`codecs` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html):

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("myfile.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as myfile:
    contents = myfile.read()
    for char in contents:
        # do something with character
```

Note that in this case, Python 2 will not do automatic newline conversion, so you need to handle `\r\n` line endings explicitly.

As an alternative (Python 2), you can open the file normally and decode it afterwards; that will normalize line endings to `\n`:

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as myfile:
    contents = myfile.read().decode("utf-8-sig")
    for char in contents:
        # do something with character
```

Note that in both cases, you will end up with Unicode objects in Python 2, not strings (in Python 3, all strings are Unicode objects).

Comment: In Python 3, I think UTF-8 is the default file reading mode, making it not necessary to specify (but not a bad idea, either, if that's the explicit intention). Update: this is wrong, per comment below.

Comment: for printing each char: print char, ord( char ).

Comment: Can you explain more what do you mean with "so you need to handle \r\n line endings explicitly". Does this mean that all new lines are lost ?  If so, how to save them ?

Comment: @IvanX: UTF-8 is the default *source code* encoding. The default encoding used by `open()` is OS-dependent. On Windows, it's cp1252, for example.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying. I was doing quick testing on Linux only which was how I arrived at that assumption.

Comment: @WebOrCode: Normally, Python converts all line endings to single `\n`s when opening a text file (and converts them back to the system standard for newlines when writing a text file). `codecs.open()` doesn't change the newline format used by the OS.

Comment: @TimPietzcker The default encoding is as per `locale.getpreferredencoding`, and I'd expect it to vary according to the user settings on Windows.